# Want to run two separate react app on single domain without subdomain

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-s3, react-router, amazon-cloudfront

Currently I have two separate react apps, running on main domain and subdomain,
Main app running on https://example.com/ and
admin app running on https://admin.example.com/

Now I want to merge both apps into same domain

Main app on same url
https://example.com/

admin app on
https://example.com/admin

How to do that?
My apps are hosted on AWS s3 bucket.

Comment: Do you mean main app should run on https://example.com/?

Comment: yes, second app want to runn on https://example.com/admin

Answer (score 0):

If you want CloudFront to request your content from a directory in your AWS resource or your custom origin, enter the directory path, beginning with a slash (/). CloudFront appends the directory path to the value of Origin Domain Name, for example, cf-origin.example.com/production/images

For example, suppose you've specified the following values for your distribution:

- Origin Domain Name – An Amazon S3 bucket named DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET
- Origin Path – /production
- Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) – example.com

When a user enters example.com/index.html in a browser, CloudFront sends a request to Amazon S3 for DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/production/index.html.

When a user enters example.com/acme/index.html in a browser, CloudFront sends a request to Amazon S3 for DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/production/acme/index.html.

Best,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

First you need to adjust your admin app react router configuration. Here is an excellent article on how to do it: [How to deploy a React app to a subdirectory](https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1). Next, your nginx configuration should look like the following:

```
location / {
    root <path/to/your/main/app>;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
location /admin {
    alias <path/to/your/second/app>;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
}
```

If you can put your second app under `admin` subdirectory of your first app (e.g. first app at `/var/www/html` and second app at `/var/www/html/admin`, nginx configuration can be made even more simple:

```
root </path/to/your/main/app>;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
location /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
}
```